# With static IP on Hyper-V ping to VM fails

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, dhcp, static-ip

I have configured a VM on Hyper-v. With the VM network adapter configured to receive DHCP the ping works fine but when I set it to static IP address ping from host to VM always returns time out .I am using Externalswitch for sharing the connection with the VM. Below is the snapshot of the Externalswitch configuration.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check if IP addresses are in the same subnet and servers resolve in DNS correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This led me to correcting my CIDR range. `nmcli` automatically set my static IP to /32 but specifying /24 fixed my issue.